# References of version 2 of an arXiv paper not added in Google Scholar

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar, preprint

I first uploaded a paper to arXiv and it was correctly added to my Google Scholar profile. After a few months, I made some modifications to the article, uploading a second version to arXiv (this revised version included some new references too).

However Google Scholar, despite correctly pointing to the (revised) second version of the arXiv paper, did not recognize the new references.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: A good point @astronat, I was a bit off. Comment duly deleted.